# Lost Phone, I want to locate my phone

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, lost-phone

Can I get the location of my phone it does have WhatsApp on it,
I lost it about 20 hours ago and it was online(life) on WhatsApp 11 hours ago
I tried google-locator but it is out of reach because I switched off background data.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [lost-phone tag-wiki](/tags/lost-phone/info)? You're not the first asking this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try locating your phone using Google's *find my device* option. Just go to [Android.com/devicemanager](http://Android.com/devicemanager) log in, and it will show you the location of the device. If it doesn't show your location, in that case your location option is probably off, or your phone is off, or it was factory reset.

WhatsApp doesn't have a function to find your phone. So unless you had a different app that does that, you might be out of luck.